# Creating multiple pdf reports from single Rnw file

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I have a Rnw file like below. I'd like to create multiple pdf files by changing data inside the Rnw file dynamically.

```
\begin{document}
\newpage
<<code,comment="",echo=FALSE,include=FALSE>>=
x=source('myR.R')
y=print.xtable(xtable((someDF)))
z<-someDF$col1
@

\title{My Title}    
\textsc{Data: \Sexpr{z}}
\Sexpr{y}
\end{document}
```

On the first run, I need the pdf file to be `col1.pdf` and the value of z be `z<-someDF$col1`. On the second run file created should be `col2.pdf` and value of z updated as `z<-someDF$col2`. The number of runs shall be decided on the run, and stored in a variable say `run`

Can something like this can be done?